# Manage duplicate jar files using ant and ivy

Tags: java, ant, ivy

HI,

I am using ant build script to build my java app and utilizing Ivy to manage its  dependency.

As my application is dependent/subset of other application(Main App), when running it, I set the classpath to point to lib jars of the Main App.

As I tried to build the kit using ant and ivy, it includes/retrieve all the jars that is required as specified in ivy.xml

The problem is, some of the jar files are duplicated with with jars file in the main app folders.

Is there a way to set the classpath in build.xml to ignore retrieving jar files that already exist in the main app's lib folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to exclude file items explicitly within a  tag, but you will have to manually call them out:

```
<fileset dir="yourdir">
     <exclude name="apps/**/*Test*"/>
</fileset>
```

You might consider another approach, though. It sounds like you are mixing dependency management methods. This is why you are having a conflict... You are manually setting dependencies in MainApp's lib, and specifying other dependencies in Ivy. I urge you to consider picking one of these, and doing all of your dependency management in it.

You could publish MainApp's artifacts through Ivy, and consume that artifact in your sub-project. Ivy will manage the duplicates for you.

Alternatively, you could remove MainApp from your classpath altogether, and grab the dependencies afresh every time (Ivy caches those dependencies locally, so you won't have to re-download them, it just manages them on disk for you).

Comment: Agreed. Use ivy to manage all the class path dependencies. If you depend on another project publish it's jars into the local repository first and then run the second build.